# How to create a View Container within a UIViewController?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I can't seem to figure out how to create a container like the one in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12574544/896334

Can anyone provide steps? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a project using storyboarding and in Object Library you will find the ContainerView, now just drag and drop it on your viewController and It will work for you. screenShot will help you

[image]

Comment: Thanks, not sure how I missed that.