# Dynamic uiview layout with auto layout

Tags: ios, uiview, interface-builder, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I'm working with autolayout and its been going very well so far but right now I am at lost as to the way to proceed to achieve the design I want.

I got a a small questionnaire with 2 sections. Each section is embedded in its own UIView with each section's view containing an uiview per question.

My problem is, I want to add the question dynamically, say only show question 2 of section 1 when the user enter a certain input in question 1.

[image: Layout desired]

I first attempted to show each section by using using addsubview for the question view and reseting the frame of the section dynamically using setFrame: before realizing this method was not gonna work properly with autolayout (for example, since my questionaire is contained in a scrollview, scrolling will call the loadsubviews method on the scrollview and reset the section's view to their original size...)

What would be the proper way to achieve this? Using a tableview with a variable size perhaps? Or programatically creating layoutconstraint?

Comment: Seems to me like using a tableview would be much much easier

Comment: Yes I'm attempting to do it with a staticell tableview and simply resizing the tableviewsize with an height constraint depending on how many questions are shown (also hiding the question cell that are not shown) is a very easy way to achieve this. I feel like its a bit hackish but its but if it saves me from adding constraints programatically...

Comment: All you need to do is make a tableviewcell that is for a single question, then each "section" is a table view section, and each row in that section is a question, no constraints for dynamic sizing is needed at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is Dan F suggestion of using a tableview. I used the answer in this great post https://stackoverflow.com/a/12574544/865632 to create static tableview in view container allowing me to have static cell uitableview without having to cluster my main view controller with dummy tablecontroller